# What is the difference between greedy and non-greedy approach to Regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Can any one help me to understand the difference between two approaches to regular expressions, with some suitable examples?

- greedy
- non-greedy

Thanks

Comment: Where [have you looked?](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=ruby+greedy+regex) This is covered by all regular expression documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chekout http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Greediness refers to the quantity of times the regex engine will try to match certain set of characters. The way to state the "greediness" of a regex expression is using the special characters `*`, `+`, `?` and `{}`.

Consider

```
str = "asdfasdfbbbb"
r1 = /b/
r2 = /(asdf)*/
r3 = /b{3}/
r4 = /.*/
```

Matching these regex against **str** will result in:

**r1** matching *"asdfasdf **b** bbb"* (non-greedy, tries to match *b* just once)
**r2** matching *"**asdfasdf** bbbb"* (greedy, tries to match *asdf* as many times as possible)
**r3** matching *"asdfasdf **bbb** b"* (non-greedy, matches *b* exactly 3 times)
**r4** matching *"**asdfasdfbbbb**"* (ULTRA-greedy, matches almost any character as many times as possible)

As regex are means to represent specific text patterns, it's not like greediness it's a matter of approach. You will sometimes need to match three times *foo*(`/(foo){3}/`) or infinite times *bar*(`/(bar)*/`).

Answer (score 10):

In greedy approach regex pattern tend to consume maximum characters in a source string.For example

```
textstr = "bcabdcab"
textstr.gsub!(/(.*)ab/, "xxx")  
# this will match whole `bcabdcab` and return `xxx`
```

Here `*` is a greedy quantifier.In non greedy approach regex engine returns when it satisfies the matching criteria.To make a quantifier non-greedy append `?`

```
textstr = "bcabdcab"
textstr.gsub!(/(.*?)ab/, "xxx")  
# this will match only `bcab` part and return `xxxdcab`
```

`gsub` returns a copy of str(first argument) with the all occurrences of pattern substituted for the second argument

Comment: if the `gsub` function is to gett all occurences of the pattern substituted, the second should return 'xxxxxx'.

Answer (score 2):

- `*` - (0 or more) greedy matching
- `+` - (1 or more) greedy matching
- `*?` - (0 or more) non-greedy matching
- `+?` - (1 or more) non-greedy matching

Comment: Is there any specific situations- when to chose the `greedy` or `non-greedy` approach?

Comment: for more about ruby regex expressions see http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/regexes/